# Remove item from list Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have a document containg a list. When I write the document it prints

```
['γύρισε στις φυλακές δομοκού κουφοντίνας huffpost greece']
['australia']
[]
['brasil']
[]
['canada']
[]
['españa']
[]
```

What I want is to remove the `[]` characters. So far I've done the following.

```
for file_name in list_of_files:

    with open(file_name, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as inf:
        lst = []
        for line in inf:
            #special characters removal
            line = line.lower()
            line = re.sub('\W+',' ', line )
            line = word_tokenize(line)
            #stopwords removal
            line = ' '.join([word for word in line if word not in stopwords_dict])
            line = line.split('\n')
            line = list(filter(None, line))
            lst.append(line)
        inf.close()
```

Which removes some `''` from inside the empty `[]`, which seems reasonable. I have tried several approaches such as `strip`, `remove()` and `[x for x in strings if x]` without success. I am rather inexperienced, what am I missing?

update:
the initial text looks like this

```
Εκτέλεσαν τον δημοσιογράφο Γιώργο Καραϊβάζ στον Άλιμο | HuffPost Greece
                    Australia
                
                    Brasil
                
                    Canada
                
                    España
                
                    France
                
                    Ελλάδα (Greece)
                
                    India
                
                    Italia
                
                    日本 (Japan)
                
                    한국 (Korea)
                
                    Québec (en français)
                
                    United Kingdom
                
                    United States
                
Ελλάδα (Greece)
```

Update:

And I am writing the list to a file like this

```
for line in lst:
            outf.write("%s\n" % line)
        outf.close()
```

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Comment: @mkrieger1 I added text from one of the files of the set, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to remove the empty lines by channging:

```
line = list(filter(None, line))
            lst.append(line)
```

to

```
lst.append(line)
lst = list(filter(None, lst))
```

Apologies, it was a trivial mistake, thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're writing the lists itself after you're appending all of the items in the file. If you want to print the items of a list in python without the surrounding '[' and ']', then just loop over each item and print like so:

```
for item in list:
    outf.write("%s\n" % item)
```

and for a list of lists

```
for list in lists:
    for item in list:
        outf.write("%s\n" % item)
```

if your output line always contains just one of each '[' and ']' then you can get what's in between with something like

```
for line in lst:
    open_split = line.split('[')
    after_open = open_split[1] if len(open_split) > 0 else ""
    closed_split = after_open.split(']')
    in_between_brackets = closed_split[0]
    outf.write("%s\n" % in_between_brackets)
```

A short hand fragile version of the above split method can be done like so:

```
for line in lst:
      outf.write("%s\n" % line.split('[')[1].split(']')[0])
```

Comment: I 've added relevant information on the question regarding your observations, thanks.

Comment: oh I see. Try debugging the line you're outputting. If there is always only 1 of each '[' and ']' then you could do something like line.split('[')[1].split(']')[0]
But if it doesn't contain both it will break

Comment: With `outf.write("%s\n" % line.split('[')[1].split(']')[0])` I get `IndexError: list index out of range`

Answer (score 1):

If the expected result from the clean is like this

```
γύρισε στις φυλακές δομοκού κουφοντίνας huffpost greece
australia
brasil
canada
españa
```

Then this code below would help you.

```
import re

with open('original.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()

with open('cleaned.txt', 'w') as f:
    # Remove chars like [, ] and '
    result = re.sub("\[|\]|'", '', data)
    # Remove the extra lines (replace 2 \n by 1).
    result = re.sub('\\n\\n', '\\n', result)
    f.write(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

After you remove the stop words you likely don't want to:

```
line = line.split('\n')
line = list(filter(None, line))
```

You likely want to inspect what is left and just `continue` if it is "nothing"

```
import re # mocking for NLTK

stopwords_dict = {
    "huffpost": True
}

text_in = '''
Εκτέλεσαν τον δημοσιογράφο Γιώργο Καραϊβάζ στον Άλιμο | HuffPost Greece
                    Australia

                    Brasil

                    Canada

                    España

                    France

                    Ελλάδα (Greece)

                    India

                    Italia

                    日本 (Japan)

                    한국 (Korea)

                    Québec (en français)

                    United Kingdom

                    United States

Ελλάδα (Greece)
'''

'''
This emulates NLTK.word_tokenize
'''
def word_tokenize(text):
    return re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', text).split()

lst = []
for line in text_in.splitlines():
    line = line.lower()
    line = re.sub('\W+',' ', line )
    line_tokens = word_tokenize(line)
    line_tokens = [token for token in line_tokens if token not in stopwords_dict]

    # after cleaning a line, if there is nothing left skip
    if not line_tokens:
        continue

    line = ' '.join(line_tokens)
    lst.append(line)

with open("file_out.txt", "w", encoding='utf-8') as file_out:
    for line in lst:
        file_out.write("%s\n" % line)
```

This is give you a file with the contents of:

```
εκτέλεσαν τον δημοσιογράφο γιώργο καραϊβάζ στον άλιμο greece
australia
brasil
canada
españa
france
ελλάδα greece
india
italia
日本 japan
한국 korea
québec en français
united kingdom
united states
ελλάδα greece
```

Which is what you are hoping for (I think).

Comment: I get `AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'splitlines'` any thoughts?

Comment: my example uses a string `text_in` you might replicate that with `text_in = inf.read()`

Comment: I implemented your code and I am still getting empty `[]` lines in output text.